# ajax load of youtube frame using ajax where youtube id is text input

Tags: ajax, wordpress, jquery, youtube

I have created metabox for my custom post type in wordpress theme.My Meta field contain text type. Input value to this text type is youtube video id. Youtube Video preview is updating only after publishing that post. How can I update video url and can see preview instantly without publishing that post.

```
add_action('save_post', 'my_metabox_save');
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'my_metabox' );

function my_metabox () {

add_meta_box('my_metabox_id', "my metabox", 'my_metabox_cb', 'custome-post', 'normal', 'high');

}


##### MY metabox callback ########
function my_metabox_cb () {

wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'myplugin_noncename' );


?>

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

<div class="my-video-id>
<h2>Enter Youtube Video ID</h2>

<input type="text" style="width: 100%;" name="my_youtube_id" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($_GET['post'], 'my_youtube_id', true); ?>" />

<?php if (get_post_meta($_GET['post'], 'my_youtube_id', true) != "") : ?>

<h2>youtube video box</h2>

<object width="600" height="400"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/a6GCy_lKYo8?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/<?php echo get_post_meta($_GET['post'], 'my_youtube_id', true); ?>?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="400" height="300"></embed></object>

</div>

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

}

function my_metabox_save ($post_id) {

 if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['myplugin_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) {
    return $post_id;
  }

  if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
    return $post_id;

  if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
      return $post_id;
  } else {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
      return $post_id;
  }

 update_post_meta($post_id, 'my_youtube_id', $_POST['my_youtube_id'],true);
```

Comment: Actually I am newbie to AJAX and Jquery. I have implemented page containing embedded YouTube .Where src attribute is my youtube url. How can I change this url instantly with ajax ,where url value is input given to my text type.Help me ,then you will get yours chocolate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks! for your suggestion ! actually i wanna post my code that what i have tried but I cant paste my code write now. Better i will post my link.

Comment: This is my link: http://pastebin.com/WEsCc512
Trying to implement it in my wordpress Metabox admin panel. Youtube video is loading only after publishing the post , How can I load it with Ajax .

Comment: Check this [Q&A](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/54822/12615) for an example of using Ajax. Try to merge that with your code and update your Question accordingly: "I tried this, but this part is not working", for example. :::: PS: it is better to add the code to the Question itself. You are free to [edit it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14006750/edit) whenever needed.

Comment: Nice to learn some basic things from you on this site.Hopes this will help me in getting better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I misread the Question the first time. To solve it, is a matter of jQuery: grab the value from the input box and modify the HTML of the embedded video div. An example:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'my_metabox' );

function my_metabox () {
    add_meta_box(
        'my_metabox_id', 
        "my metabox", 
        'my_metabox_cb', 
        'custome-post', 
        'normal', 
        'high'
    );
}

function my_metabox_cb () {
    ?>
        <div class="my-video-id">
            <h2>Enter Youtube Video ID</h2>
            <input type="text" style="width: 100%;" id="yt-id" value="" />
            <div id="yt-metabox"></div>
            <button id="yt-refresh">Refresh</button>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {   
            $("#yt-refresh").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var yt_id = $('#yt-id').val();
                $('#yt-metabox').html('<object width="600" height="400"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/a6GCy_lKYo8?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/' + yt_id + '?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="400" height="300"></embed></object>');
            });
        });
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @brasofilo !I m just going through yours helpful suggestion.